# The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Possuo um projeto que esta no meu servidor iis e esta funcionando na maioria das maquinas, mas em algumas esta sendo recebida a mensagem:

```
The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
```

Tenho em meu controler:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Salvar(Ramal ramal, HttpPostedFileBase upload, int CallSource)
        {

            ViewBag.CallSource = CallSource;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string AuxExtensao;
                byte[] auxFoto;
```

e em minha view:

```
@model Ramais.Models.Ramal

@using (Html.BeginForm("Salvar", "Ramais", new { CallSource = (int)ViewBag.CallSource }, FormMethod.Post,
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Tenho 50 maquinas ok e duas apresentando esta mensagem quando o usuario salva as informações.
Se o mesmo vai em outra maquina funciona...

Alguém já passou por isto?

Comment: você já verificou a versão do navegador, se está atualizado? em quais navegadores e a partir de qual versão de navegador seu sistema funciona?

Comment: Já passei por isso e era quando clicava duas vezes no botão enviar.

Comment: todas maquinas internet explorer 11